# how to define excel pivot range that starts on the nth row?

Tags: excel, range, pivot

I know that when selecting A:F as a range in a pivot table,  excel knows  to ignore rows that are not in the usedrange.

i want to skip the first n rows so that the pivot range will be A6:F1000000.

since the range is explicitly defined, I dont believe excel can perform any optimization

do you know what is the right way to skip the first n lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using about a named range like this:-

```
=Sheet1!$A$7:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$F,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$A:$A),6)
```

assuming your columns are the same length and the first column contains numbers?

Comment: i tried:=OFFSET(sh1!$A$6,0,0,COUNTA(sh1!$A:$A)-1,COUNTA(sh1!$6:$6)-1)... i know that offset is bad but i also remember that there is an issue with the "a1:a" +n trick...i cant remember what it was...

Comment: I think it's not ideal to use it with INDIRECT but as far as I know using INDEX like this would be OK - maybe others can comment.